# How can i modify resetpassword email in Yii2 ? the main email does not have resettoken

Tags: php, email, yii2

```
   public function sendEmail()
{
    /* @var $Users Users */
    $Users = Users::findOne(['username' => $this->username]);

    if ($Users){
        if (!Users::isPasswordResetTokenValid($Users->password_reset_token)) {
            $Users->generatePasswordResetToken();
        }
        if ($Users->save()){
            return \Yii::$app->mailer->compose('passwordResetToken', ['Users' => $Users])
                ->setFrom([\Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => \Yii::$app->name . ' noreply'])
                ->setTo($this->username)
                ->setSubject('Password reset for' . \Yii::$app->name)
                ->send();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

That is my function to send reset Token but there is not  a reset token in the email,

Answer (score 0):

According to [Yii guide documents](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-mail-basemailer.html#compose()-detail), passing the view file as you have will result in the php function strip_tags() being applied. This will also remove any php tags, as well as html tags, from the file.

I think you may need to pass the view file as `passwordResetToken-html`.

So your function looks like this:

```
    public function sendEmail()
{
    /* @var $Users Users */
    $Users = Users::findOne(['username' => $this->username]);

    if ($Users){
        if (!Users::isPasswordResetTokenValid($Users->password_reset_token)) {
            $Users->generatePasswordResetToken();
        }
        if ($Users->save()){
            return \Yii::$app->mailer->compose('passwordResetToken-html', ['Users' => $Users])
                ->setFrom([\Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => \Yii::$app->name . ' noreply'])
                ->setTo($this->username)
                ->setSubject('Password reset for' . \Yii::$app->name)
                ->send();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thank you, i foud it in common/mails, (LOL)  and it is already modified :)